# Div hide/show javascript that hides one div and displays another

Tags: javascript, html

I have a show/hide javascript, magicShow:

```
function magicShow(e) {
    ele = document.getElementById(e);
    if (ele.style.display == "none") {
        ele.style.opacity = 0;
        ele.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";
        ele.style.display = "";
        valueop = 1;
        setTimeout("fadeIn()", openingdelay)
    } else {
        valueop = 9;
        setTimeout("fadeOut()", closingdelay)
    }
}

function fadeOut() {
    if (valueop < 1) {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        return false
    }
    ele.style.opacity = valueop / 10;
    ele.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + valueop * 10 + ")";
    valueop = valueop - 1;
    setTimeout("fadeOut()", closingspeed)
}

function fadeIn() {
    if (valueop > 10) {
        return false
    }
    ele.style.opacity = valueop / 10;
    ele.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + valueop * 10 + ")";
    valueop = valueop + 1;
    setTimeout("fadeIn()", openingspeed)
}
var openingdelay = 100;
var closingdelay = 100;
var openingspeed = 15;
var closingspeed = 15
```

On two adjacent links I put this code:

```
<a href="#" onClick="magicShow('showdiv-A'); return false;">Link A</a>
<a href="#" onClick="magicShow('showdiv-B'); return false;">Link B</a>
```

When clicked/tapped, each link displays a hidden div. Tap the link again and the div disappears. Both divs can be open or both closed at the same time. I put Div A and Div B in different positions so they don't overlap. But would it be possible to have the divs overlap and modify the script behavior so that:

- if div A is visible and you tap link B, div A disappears and div B appears;
- if div B is visible and you tap link A, div B disappears and div A appears;

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765308/toggling-between-two-divs-by-one-click-button) has a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLLwq/2/) which doesn't do that, but it might be a basis for a solution. The solution should have two links, and not lose the function of tapping to make a div disappear. Also, I'd prefer to do this without jquery.

PS: Questions like this have been asked here, but always (I think) involving a single link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpel way of doing it

```js
    function magicShow(e) {
      ele = document.getElementById(e);
      if (ele.style.display == "none") {
          ele.style.opacity = 0;
          ele.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";
          ele.style.display = "";
          valueop = 1;
          setTimeout("fadeIn()", openingdelay)
      } else {
          valueop = 9;
          setTimeout("fadeOut()", closingdelay)
      }
      if (e == "showdiv-B") {
        document.getElementById("showdiv-A").style.display = "none"
      } else if (e == "showdiv-A") {
        document.getElementById("showdiv-B").style.display = "none"
      }
    }
    
    function fadeOut() {
      if (valueop < 1) {
          ele.style.display = "none";
          return false
      }
      ele.style.opacity = valueop / 10;
      ele.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + valueop * 10 + ")";
      valueop = valueop - 1;
      setTimeout("fadeOut()", closingspeed)
    }
    
    function fadeIn() {
      if (valueop > 10) {
          return false
      }
      ele.style.opacity = valueop / 10;
      ele.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + valueop * 10 + ")";
      valueop = valueop + 1;
      setTimeout("fadeIn()", openingspeed)
    }
    var openingdelay = 100;
    var closingdelay = 100;
    var openingspeed = 15;
    var closingspeed = 15
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="magicShow('showdiv-A'); return false;">Link A</a>
<a href="#" onClick="magicShow('showdiv-B'); return false;">Link B</a>
<div style="display: none;" id="showdiv-A">
Showing div-A
</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="showdiv-B">
Showing div-B
</div>
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to make your code into a snippet so others can easily see the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it. Instead of the **display** property, I'm using **visibility** though. This will keep your objects in place even if it's invisible.
Everything's pretty straight-forward. Tell the function which object you want to show and in the switch block we figure out what' needs to be hidden.
As a side note: In case you're wondering, it's possible to give parameters to a callback function of setTimout() after the delay parameter.

```js
var openingdelay = 100;
var closingdelay = 100;
var openingspeed = 15;
var closingspeed = 15

function magicShow(action) {
  var elementToShow;
  var elementToHide;
  switch (action) {
    case "showdiv-A":
      elementToShow = document.getElementById("showdiv-A");
      elementToHide = document.getElementById("showdiv-B");
      break;
    case "showdiv-B":
      elementToHide = document.getElementById("showdiv-A");
      elementToShow = document.getElementById("showdiv-B");
      break;
  }
  if (elementToHide.style.visibility == "visible") {
    setTimeout(fadeOut, closingdelay, elementToHide, 10)
  }

  setTimeout(fadeIn, openingdelay, elementToShow, 0)
}

function fadeOut(element, alpha) {
  if (alpha < 1) {
    element.style.visibility = "hidden";
    return false;
  }
  element.style.opacity = alpha / 10;
  element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + alpha * 10 + ")";
  alpha = alpha - 1;
  setTimeout(fadeOut, closingspeed, element, alpha);
}

function fadeIn(element, alpha) {
  if (alpha > 10) {
    return false;
  }
  element.style.opacity = alpha / 10;
  element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + alpha * 10 + ")";
  element.style.visibility = "visible";
  alpha = alpha + 1;
  setTimeout(fadeIn, openingspeed, element, alpha);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="magicShow('showdiv-A'); return false;">Link A</a>
<a href="#" onClick="magicShow('showdiv-B'); return false;">Link B</a>
<div id="showdiv-A" style="visibility:hidden;">I'm div 1</div>
<div id="showdiv-B" style="visibility:hidden;">I'm div 2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this solution the divs aren't hidden by a second tap/click